# how to remove data from an application variable

Tags: asp.net, session

i wanted to add to my website the option of seeing the usernames of the people that are logged in my website as a list.
i did it using the Application state so when a person loges in the application variable adds it to itself. 
but when a person loges out of the website i need to remove his username from the list and i'm having trouble with this... any code suggestions?
in the Login page:

```
Application["UserList"] += Session["UserName"].ToString() + "<br/>";
```

and i tried this in the Logout page but it didnt work...:

```
String name = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    Application.Remove(name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would use something along the lines of this:

```
Application["UserList"].ToString.Replace(Session["UserName"].ToString() + "<br/>", "");
```

But you really should not try manage a string. Use something like a HashTable and store that object in the application state.  It's far easier to manage key/value pairs in a dictionary type construct.

Also it separates the data from the formatting which gives you much greater control over the output.